# Matlab: How to decrease the precision of calculations in matlab to let's say 4 digits?

Tags: matlab, precision

I am wondering what would be the way to tell Matlab that all computations need to be done and continued with let's say 4 digits.

format long or other formats I think is for showing the results with specific precision, not for their value precision.

Comment: can you give an example please ?

Comment: @Umar Actually based on my previous experience I think it would be better to avoid giving lengthy examples and codes that I am using, since it makes the question seem unnecessarily complicated. And so I always to simplify my question or at least give a concise and simplified version of my code. For this case my actual code is long, and making a simplified code would not add anything to help viewers answer. I think my question is more general than needing a specific example. :)

Comment: I guess no. However, in your code, you can limit the precision using [round](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `digits`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/digits.html

`digits(d)` sets the current VPA accuracy to d significant decimal digits. The value d must be a positive integer greater than 1 and less than 2^29 + 1.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I checked it out, it seems that you should put that specific number in "vpa" to have it to the given precision. But I have some computations that I cannot put them in vpa, what shall I do? there is no way to generally limit the precision for all computations?

for instance:
`digits(2);`
`1/3`
does not give with two digit precision you should necessarily put it in vpa(1/3)

Comment: It seems it only exists in symbolic math toolbox.

Answer (score 2):

Are you hoping to increase performance or save memory by not using double precision? If so, then variable precision arithmetic and `vpa` (part of the Symbolic Math toolbox) are probably not the right choice. Instead, you might consider [fixed point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic). This type of math is mostly used on microcontrollers and architectures with memory address widths of less than 32 bits or that lack dedicated floating point hardware. In Matlab you'll need the [Fixed Point Designer toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/fixed-point-designer/). You can read more about the capabilities [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/fixed-point-basics.html).